# Feature importance using logistic regression in pyspark

Tags: python, logistic-regression, pyspark

I am using logistic regression in `PySpark`. I have after splitting train and test dataset

```
LR = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label', maxIter=some_iter)
LR_model = LR.fit(train)
```

I displayed `LR_model.coefficientMatrix` but I get a huge matrix. How do I select the important features and get the name of their related columns ?